# How do I refresh the RecyclerView when an image is clicked?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know this questions has been asked in the past. For some reason I can't seem to get it to work even though I tried using

```
understoodLanguageListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in my Activity file. Here is my code

Fragment file containing RecyclerView.

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/color_list"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Item layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/colorText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/colorImage"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icn_close_bluepurple" />
```

Adapter code:
public class ColorsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
Context context;
List<String> list;

public ColorsListAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.colors_item,parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(list.get(position));
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ColorsManager colorsManager = new ColorsManager();
            colorsManager.deleteFromColorsList(holder.textView.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorText);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorImage);
    }
}
```

}

Activity code is as follows:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<String> list;
UnderstoodLanguageListAdapter understoodLanguageListAdapter;
---
---
@Override
protected void initialize(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.color_list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    ColorsManager colorsManager = new ColorsManager();
    list = colorsManager.getUnderstoodLanguageList();
    colorsListAdapter = new ColorsListAdapter(this, list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(colorsListAdapter);
}
```

Any advice/tips about the fix is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change in adapter class like replace bellow code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.textView.setText(list.get(position));
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ColorsManager colorsManager = new ColorsManager();
          colorsManager.deleteFromColorsList(holder.textView.getText().toString());
    }
});
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView textView;
ImageView imageView;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorText);
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorImage);
}
}
```

with new code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(list.get(position));
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView textView;
ImageView imageView;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorText);
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorImage);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int pos = getAdapterPosition(); 
            ColorsManager colorsManager = new ColorsManager();
            colorsManager.deleteFromColorsList(list.get(pos));
            notifyItemRemoved(pos);             
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try `notifyItemRemoved(position)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to let adapter know that some changes has been made in certain position, to achieve that you need to use some callback (Listener), which has to be passed from your View -> Adapter -> ViewHolder or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instance of `ColorManager` every time user clicks ImageView.
This new instance is obviously different from one that you used in `initialize()`.

So, the item in new instance is updated and not the list that you passed to recycler adapter